# Align all values by classtype in vaadin table?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I have a vaadin `Table` and would like to align all columns that have number class types (eg `BigDecimal`, `Integer`, `Double` to the right.

It's possible to set alignment per table column id with:

`table.setColumnAlignment("username", Align.RIGHT);`

But I'd prefer setting the alignment per classtype. Is that possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could override the `setVisibleColumns` method:

```
new Table() {

    @Override
    public void setVisibleColumns(Object... visibleColumns) {
        super.setVisibleColumns(visibleColumns);
        for (Object propertyId : visibleColumns) {
            setPropertyAlignment(propertyId);
        }
    }

    private void setPropertyAlignment(Object propertyId) {

        Class<?> clazzProperty = getContainerDataSource().getType(propertyId);
        if (clazzProperty.isAssignableFrom(Number.class)) {
            super.setColumnAlignment(propertyId, Align.RIGHT);
        }
        else {
            super.setColumnAlignment(propertyId, Align.LEFT);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Number.class.isAssignableFrom(clazzProperty)` ?